# Call web service with attachment

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws

I am having a rather frustrating issue trying to call a web service that requires an attachment.

This is the error:

> Unexpected Attachment type =class
>   java.lang.Object

from here:

> class="com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$AttachmentBuilder"
>   file="ResponseBuilder.java" line="250"
>   method="createAttachmentBuilder"

The method the web proxy gives me is this:

```
  public Reply putDocument(
    @WebParam(targetNamespace="uri:put.document", partName="request", name="request")
      StoreType request,
    @WebParam(targetNamespace="", partName="put", name="put")
      Object put);
```

What I cannot figure out is what to pass in for "put", which is only defined as an Object.

I have tried:

```
byte[]
String
DataHandler(ByteArrayDataSource)
uri.put_document.ObjectFactory.createPut(byte[])
AttachmentPart
```

I have also tried looking for the code but haven't had luck so far.

EDIT: WSDL is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<definitions targetNamespace="urn:fer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             xmlns:tns="urn:fer"
             xmlns:get="uri:get.document"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
             xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/">
  <types>
      <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="uri:get.document"
                    schemaLocation="../xsd/getDocument.xsd"/>
      </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="putDocument">
    <part name="request" element="put:request"/>    
    <part name="put" element="put:put"/>
  </message>
  <message name="putDocumentReply">
    <part name="reply" element="put:reply"/>    
  </message>
  <portType name="FrontEndRepository">
    <operation name="putDocument">
      <input message="tns:putDocument"/>
      <output message="tns:putDocumentReply"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="frontEndRepositoryPortSOAP11Binding"
           type="tns:FrontEndRepository">
    <soap:binding style="document"
                  transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="putDocument">
      <soap:operation style="document"
                      soapAction="putDocument"/>
      <input>
        <mime:multipartRelated>
          <mime:part>
            <soap:body use="literal" parts="request"/>
          </mime:part>
          <mime:part>
            <mime:content part="put" type="binary"/>
          </mime:part>
        </mime:multipartRelated>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="FrontEndRepository">
    <port name="FrontEndRepository"
          binding="tns:frontEndRepositoryPortSOAP11Binding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:7101/FER-FrontEndrepository-context-root/frontEndRepositoryPort"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: We need your WSDL. Also look here https://jax-rpc.dev.java.net/whitepaper/1.1.2/attachments-howto.html

Comment: Can you pass it null or a dummy String?  Any Serializable non-Object instance seems likley to succeed.

Comment: Which implementation of JAX-WS are you using and in which container ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect the type attribute in the mime:content element to contain a MIME type, eg. "application/octet-stream", "application/pdf" or "text/plain" rather than "binary".

Using javax.activation.DataHandler should work, and I think you should be able to fix the MIME type of the attachment, and then use a DataHandler instance or a type appropriate to the MIME type (eg. java.awt.Image for "image/jpeg").

You say you have tried a DataHandler, but you haven't provided the exception for that case. If that still fails, what happens when you try it?

Comment: The error was occuring when the service defintion was loaded, not when the operation was invoked. So this needed to be fixed for all definitions in the WSDL.